# Java Array index out of bounds while making a string

Tags: java, arrays, exception, random, int

I was making a code that makes some unique integers in a string and i suddenly ran into an exception and i don't quite get what is the problem here, because i was almost done. And now what is happening i don't know.

Here's my code:

```
String[] res = new String[12];
        int[] ia = {1, 6, 9};
        int[] ai = {97, 79, 8};
        int[] a = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i] = (ia[new Random().nextInt(3)] ^ (ai[new Random().nextInt(3)] * i));
            for(int j = 0; j < res.length; j++){
                if(a[i] >= j){
                    res[j * i] = "J:" + (a[i] * a[new Random().nextInt(10)]); //exception
                } else if(a[i] <= j){
                    res[j * i] = "J:" + (-(a[i] * a[new Random().nextInt(10)]));
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the exception that is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at testy.main(unique.java:15)
```

Comment: arrays are *zero based*. You're accessing the 13th element. Looking for one of the many dups of this.

Comment: this code have so many errors that i cant even find a good line of code except the declarations of an arrays ....

Comment: What @MatejSpili said. For one thing, you should *not* be creating new `Random()` objects like that. You'll end up getting the exact same number numerous times. Create one at the start of your loop, and use the same one for everything there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the maximum values of i and j. You will see that res[j * i] will exceed the space you have allocated for it and hence the out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0):

In your first for you go from 0 to 9 (a.length = 10). In the second you go from 0 to 11 (res.length=12).

the `j*i` in `res[j * i]` will exceed the limit of res (12) with the simple values of 2 and 10.